# How to calculate progress of a fetch request in javascript / jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending this fetch request and the app is using a progress bar to show loading state, I wanted to create steps manually like demonstrated in the code below but it seems not working, only half of the progress is visible to the user, the last half is basically a one step, the function hang on `return response.json()` I guess.

```
  free = () => {
    self.setState({ percent: 10, loadingState: "You're in" });
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          self.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
          console.log('NOT_FOUND');
        }
        else if (response.status === 200) {
          self.setState({ percent: 30, loadingState: 'DB_200_OK' });
          return response.json()
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        self.setState({ percent: 50, loadingState: "Parsing JSON" });
        self.setState({
          loadingState: 'Building the UI',
          keys: data.keys,
          loading: false,
          ok: true,
          percent: 70,
        })
        if (self.state.keys.length === 0) {
          this.setState({ empty: true, percent: 90, })
        } else {
          this.setState({ empty: false, percent: 90, })
        }
        this.setState({ loadingState: 'Almost done', })
      }).catch(err => console.log('JSON parse error'));
  }
```

How can I show the correct progress of the function execution without using setTimeout or similar, I tried this got packets received so far but I am not sure how to get size of data

```
  var reader = response.body.getReader();
  reader.read().then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState` is async, if you want `setState` after another one you need to do like this:

```
this.setState(
  {
    keys: data.keys
  },
  () => {
    if (this.state.keys.length === 0) {
      this.setState({ empty: true, percent: 90 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ empty: false, percent: 90 });
    }
  }
);
```